# [deezer][android] SDK Player state going to stop

Tags: android, audio-streaming, deezer

I use Deezer SDK 1.0.18, I face a problem with the player state machine. Usually, the states go like this:

```
INITIALIZING -> READY -> WAITING_FOR_DATA -> PLAYING
```

which is OK, but sometimes (often with music that haven't been played before, the states go like this :

```
INITIALIZING -> READY -> WAITING_FOR_DATA -> STOPPED
```

What could be the reason for the player to stop while loading the data? 
Is there a way to fallback from this to keep loading the data and eventually play the track? 
I known the track is working since if I retry reading it, it will work.

Thank you deer Deezer staff.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in the 0.10.19 version

Comment: Hi @Tom, the issue is not fixed in 0.10.19. Also, the bug happens even in the "stable" version of the SDK (v0.10.16). Do you have any solution? Thank you.

Comment: We can't reproduce this issue anymore since 0.10.19 version. Can you provide sample project ?